# Cookie: ASP.NET SessionId Issue

Tags: .net, asp.net, session, cookies

I have a load generator that appends a ASP.NET_SessionId to the Cookie when making a Soap test call from Machine A to Machine B.

```
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=gf0ouay24sdneiuicpiggn45;
```

However, when I'm running the soap test hitting my local server it doesn't have an ASP.NET_Session variable in the cookie.

Why is this happening?

UPDATE:

I'm getting this issue now on the server:

Forms authentication failed for the request. Reason: The ticket supplied was invalid.

I've followed this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/omar/archive/2006/08/20/108307.aspx

But to no avail.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is the local IIS Server installed on the computer, or the built-in web server in Visual Studio?

Comment: No it's not using Cassini. I have an IIS server hosting it.

Comment: I'm unsure, but are cookie names allowed to have a "."? Maybe try ASPNET_SessionId=

Answer (score 0):

If you're piggybacking on the built-in ASP.NET Session Id, ensure your web app isn't running in cookieless mode. Sessionless pages do not send session ID cookies.

Try explicitly modifying the web.config [sessionState element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(VS.71).aspx) on your local server
For example:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false"
```

Explicitly setting this in web.config will override anything from the machine.config file or other web.config files, to ensure the configuration is correct. The reason you want to try this is because [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719558(VS.71).aspx):

> Multiple configuration files, all
>   named Web.config, can appear in
>   multiple directories[..] Each Web.config
>   file applies configuration settings to
>   its own directory and all child
>   directories [..] The root configuration
>   file named
>   systemroot\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versionNumber\CONFIG\Machine.config
>   provides ASP.NET configuration
>   settings for the entire Web server.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using WCF or ASMX?

Have you monitored the conversation with Fiddler or WireShark to see if the Set-Cookie header is being provided by the server side?

Comment: WCF... yes, it's what I use to see what the request/response is.

The SessionId is appended to the cookie when hitting cross servers.. hitting the tests locally do not send the sessionId... why???

Comment: Cookies are only sent to the same domains from which they are set. In your local setup, are you seeing a Set-Cookie header from the server before you expect to see a Cookie header from the client? If so, is the Set-Cookie header properly formed?